# C# Why does my FOR loop repeat the first loop before doing the second loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, repeat

I am on the cusp of finally finishing this problem.  I have asked a few questions, got a lot of great answer, done a fair amount of reading (know a lot more about InsertRange now - but that didn't work) and am almost at the finish, clean, short code to cover the eventualities.

So far I have created the following code (I say me, a lot from many of you + a little from me) - this all occurs on a Button_Click.

```
OutPutValue.Text = string.Empty;
List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string phrase = Value.Text;
string[] words = phrase.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r' });
int result = words.Count();
int Three = 3;
int Two = 2;
int One = 1;
int Four = 4;
int Five = 5;
int Six = 6;
```

Currently, I am pulling out the 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6 words from the words array - the array has a fixed length of 12 per entry, there can be more than one entry.

Each time I go through a FOR loop, I want to add 12 to each of the array selections so that on the next loop, I will pull the 15, 14, 13, 17, 18, 19 words from the array and so on...

My FOR loop is set up like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result; i = i + 13, Three = Three + 12, Two = Two + 12, One = One + 12, Four = Four + 12, Five = Five + 12, Six = Six + 12)
{
wordList.Add(ID.Text + '\t');
wordList.Add(IV.Text + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[Three] + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[Two] + '\t');
wordList.Add(PD.Text + '\t');
wordList.Add(PT.Text + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[One] + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[Four] + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[Five] + '\t');
wordList.Add(words[Six] + '\t');
wordList.Add(LD.Text) + '\t';
wordList.Add(LT.Text) + '\r';
sb.AppendLine(String.Join("", wordList));
}

OutPut.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

This is so that it will run, for the entire words array.  Please ignore that i = i + 13 there are good reasons for this - that are not worth explaining.

This works for a single line, I get just what i need - this output:

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

If I put in two lines, I get this output:

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

---

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

D.Text  IV.Text words[15]   words[14]   PD.Text PT.Text words[13]   words[16]   words[17]   words[18]   LD.Text LT.Text

If I put in three lines, I get this output:

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

---

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

D.Text  IV.Text words[15]   words[14]   PD.Text PT.Text words[13]   words[16]   words[17]   words[18]   LD.Text LT.Text

---

D.Text  IV.Text words[3]    words[2]    PD.Text PT.Text words[1]    words[4]    words[5]    words[6]    LD.Text LT.Text

D.Text  IV.Text words[15]   words[14]   PD.Text PT.Text words[13]   words[16]   words[17]   words[18]   LD.Text LT.Text

D.Text  IV.Text words[27]   words[26]   PD.Text PT.Text words[25]   words[28]   words[29]   words[30]   LD.Text LT.Text

And so on.

I do not understand why it is doing this?

Anyone able to point out the error that I have made, why does it keep repeating the 1st Loop before undertaking the 2nd Loop, and repeating the 1st loop and the 2nd loop before doing the 3rd loop?

Comment: You're not clearing `wordList` between each iteration, so it still contains all the values from previous iterations.

Comment: It is the sb.AppendLine - I left it in the Loop, so it was appending what it had already, which was the first loop, to the 2nd loop.  I moved it outside of the loop and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sb.AppendLine(string.Join) is in the loop.

I moved it outside of the loop and it now works.

My apologies all, realised it two secs after posting.

Comment: Still, I think there is some interesting code in there for anyone who is interested.  Took a few different ideas and came up with a solution for a problem on my own - of which I am quite proud.....but thanks to the many who contributed to my questions!!